# What is triggering my laptop to go to sleep?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, lenovo-laptop

My laptop has this annoying "feature" where randomly after waking up from sleep, it will go to sleep after 1.5 minutes of inactivity. After it starts going to sleep in 1.5 minutes, it keeps doing so after waking up until I close everything and restart it.

I've been dealing with this issue for a year now, and its very annoying to have to wake up my laptop and type in my password after stepping away for literally just 2 minutes. Is there anyway to find out what is triggering my laptop to go to sleep like this?

I have already checked, my power settings are not at fault. I brought my laptop in to Best Buy Geek Squad and they updated drivers and firmware, but the problem persists. I'm out of options, and can't afford a new laptop right now.

My laptop is Lenovo YOGA 900-13ISK, running Windows 10 Home Version 1803 OS Build 17134.407

EDIT:

- I did a google search for "scheduled maintenance sleep" but I didn't see anything related to my computer going to sleep from inactivity.
- Tried: Control Panel > Troubleshooting > View all > Power, and following prompts. Was told my power settings were set to have my computer go to sleep after too **long**, not the issue (too **short**, 1.5 minutes) I'm having, already specified my power settings were not the issue.
- Currently investigating [this article](https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/windows-10-going-sleep-mode-minutes-fixed/)...

Comment: This is a regular occurrence in Windows 10. Have you checked if scheduled maintenance is running?

Comment: Try: Control Panel > Troubleshooting > View all > Power, and follow prompts.

Comment: @dougabugg, please click on [edit] and specify what you've tried, instead of posting in Commands, as Comments is for folks who are helping but need more info. After you have done that, please click on the grey (x) and delete your comments to leave room for more of us. Also, please see 15 things to check at https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/windows-10-going-sleep-mode-minutes-fixed/ and advise when you have tried each.